# a continuous analogue of a graph theory question

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I am reading a paper and it mentions a continuous analogue of a related graph theory question that people concern. The question is that suppose $E\subset Q=[0,1]^2$ has lebesgue measure $|E|>0$, is it true that for some constant $\epsilon$ independent of $E$, one can always find four points $A, B,C,D\in E$ such that the quadrilateral figure $ABCD$  is a rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes, whose area is at least $\epsilon|E|^2$? I guess it is still an open question. What I want to ask is why people care about this question? Does it have some applications in graph theory? Thanks for any reference and help!

Comment: If you provided additional information about the related results which would justify the occurence of $\ \epsilon\!\cdot\! |E|^2\ $ then I would consider this question worthy simply by the virtue of its simplicity and unobviousness.

Comment: @piano what paper are you reading?

Comment: I don't know the reason for the occurence of $\epsilon |E|^2$...The paper just mentions the result.

Comment: This problem seems to me to be about showing that the intersection of, say, four translates of a set of a positive measure is (or is not) empty.

Comment: @piano, do your homework, read the literature or think more about the problem, find out about $\ \epsilon\!\cdot\!|E|^2$.

Comment: @Turbo, I thought that you were asking: XYZ, what are you drinking?

Comment: This would seem to be a continuous analogue of the following question: Suppose that a bipartite graph has density $p$ and lies between two copies of $[n] = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. Does there exist a copy of $C_4$ with vertices $A = (x, y)$, $B = (x', y)$, $C = (x, y')$, $D = (x', y')$, say, such that $|(x - x')(y-y')| \geq \epsilon p^2 n^2$?

Comment: @DavidConlon I think it is the analogue of this question. Thanks! And can I ask why we want to know if such copy exists?

Comment: I can't say that I know! I was just decoding it to see if I could answer it...

Comment: @piano so what paper is it?